# Why is my iOS 9 iPhone showing as ineligible device in Xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios9, xcode6.4

When I attach my iPhone 5, Xcode is showing it as ineligible device. My Xcode is 6.4 and iOS is 9.0.2. How can I solve that issue? I am new to Xcode and iOS development.

[Device List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CJgd.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use XCode 6.4 to develop against iOS 9.0.X and 9.1 devices. However, you will need to run XCode 7.X once with your device attached in order for symbols to be copied. Connect your phone to your Mac, launch XCode, go to Devices, and wait for the operation to complete. If your phone has iOS 9.1 installed, you must run XCode 7.1 for this to work. For iOS 9.0.X, you can run XCode 7.0.1 to copy symbols.

Once you do this, you will be able to push builds to your iOS 9 device from XCode 6.4.

Also note that XCode 7.1. requires either El Capitan or MacOS 10.10.5. If you do not yet want to upgrade to El Cap (XCode 6.4 will not run on El Cap), you can find the MacOS 10.10.5 update on the developer portal. Hope this helped. Fun stuff!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found this workaround useful until I upgraded my OS X.